# String value system.byte[] while coverting Base64 value to string in c#

Tags: c#, base64, byte, system, encode

I have two LDIF files from where I am reading values and using it for comparsion using c#
One of the `attribute: value` in LDIF is a base64 value, need to convert it in UTF-8 format

```
displayName:: Rmlyc3ROYW1lTGFzdE5hbWU=
```

So I thought of using string -> byte[], but I am not able to use the above displayName value as string

```
byte[] newbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(displayname);
string displaynamereadable = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newbytes);
```

In my C# code, I am doing this to retrieve the values from the ldif file

```
for(Entry entry ldif.ReadEntry() ) //reads value from ldif for particular user's
{
    foreach(Attr attr in entry)   //here attr gives attributes of a particular user
    {
        if(attr.Name.Equals("displayName"))
        {
            string attVal = attr.Value[0].ToString();       //here the value of String attVal is system.Byte[], so not able to use it in the next line
            byte[] newbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(attVal);   //here it throws an error mentioned below 
            string displaynamereadable = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(attVal);
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
```

I am trying to user attVal as String so that I can get the encoded UTf-8 value but its throwing an error.
I tried to use BinaryFormatter and MemoryStream as well, it worked but it inserted so many new chars with the original value.

Snapshot of BinaryFormatter:

```
object obj = attr.Value[0];
byte[] bytes = null;
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
      bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
      bytes = (ms.ToArray());
   }
 string d = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

So the result after encoding should be: `"FirstNameLastName"`

But it gives `"\u0002 \u004 \u004 ...................FirstNameLastName\v"`

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 was designed to send binary data through transfer channels that only support plain text, and as a result, Base64 is always ASCII text. So if `attr.Value[0]` is a byte array, just interpret those bytes as string using ASCII encoding:

```
String attVal = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(attr.Value[0] as Byte[]);
Byte[] newbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(attVal);
String displaynamereadable = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newbytes);
```

Also note, your code above was feeding `attVal` into that final line rather than `newbytes`.

Comment: @RDN If it worked, please [click the checkmark to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so the question is marked as resolved.